# cv::cuda::NvidiaOpticalFlow_2_0::create takes about 30 seconds

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, nvidia

To use the [official example script](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/cudaoptflow/samples/nvidia_optical_flow.cpp) for NvidiaOpticalFlow, I built OpenCV from source following the instructions from the [Nvidia Optical Flow SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/opticalflow/download) (with slightly modified build flags to enable JPEG, OPENEXR, and Eigen). The OpenCV version is 4.5.2. I can post the CMake options on request.

[This line](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/2a6cc95b10a5f882ae66e173067585ed50d1d0e6/modules/cudaoptflow/samples/nvidia_optical_flow.cpp#L303-L305) from the example script takes about 30 seconds. Is this normal or could there be an issue with my setup?

Other details:

- I'm on Ubuntu 20.04
- `nvidia-smi` gives `Driver Version: 470.141.03   CUDA Version: 11.4`
- To compile the example script I use CMake with: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)` and `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`.

Comment: It might be JIT compilation delay depending on **the CUDA version you used to build OpenCV or Optical Flow**, and **the GPU you are running on**.  Note that the information needed here is *not* the report from `nvidia-smi`.  There is not enough information in your question to determine this.  And its quite possible that if you have multiple CUDA versions installed, that CMake is using an "unexpected" CUDA version.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thanks for jumping in. From the build logs it looks like it's Cuda 11.3, NVIDIA GPU arch: 75, NVIDIA PTX archs: 75. GPU is RTX3090. Does that shed any light on it?

Comment: RTX 3090 is arch 86.  It could be an issue if there are lots of OpenCV kernels that are getting jit-compiled.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I can't tell if you've implicitly suggested I do something, or you're not sure what's to be done. I'm a little new to this sort of stuff. @RobertCrovella

Comment: There is a setting for the arch to compile for in OpenCV.  That is where the arch reports you gave me are coming from. The suggestion is to recompile your OpenCV (and the Optical Flow sample) specifying arch 86 (or arch 86 in addition to arch 75).

Comment: Got it. Changed 7.5 to 8.6 in `-DCUDA_ARCH_BIN:STRING=8.6 -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX:STRING=8.6`. Let's see if that works.

Comment: @RobertCrovella thank you. It worked! If you leave an answer I can mark as accepted, otherwise I will come back and do it later.

Comment: The answer will be clearer if you write it.  You just went through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to user @RobertCrovella in the comments, the delay may have been to do with JIT compilation. Indeed, when calling `create` twice in one script, the second time does not have a delay.

Whether or not that's the real reason, the root cause was that I had incorrectly specified the arch for my GPU in the OpenCV build flags. They were set as `-DCUDA_ARCH_BIN:STRING=7.5 -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX:STRING=7.5` whereas for my GPU (Nvidia RTX 3090) they should have been set as `-DCUDA_ARCH_BIN:STRING=8.6 -DCUDA_ARCH_PTX:STRING=8.6`. I rebuilt OpenCV with the correct flags and the delay went away.